# Some questions about WFS-T with Openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

Recently, I am working for a web based mapping tool with Openlayers3. I choose Postgres for database, Geoserver for map server which publish the layer from database source. The questions is listing as Below: 
1. I want to save new drawn geometry to database, how can i do:  directly connect to database, or connect to geoserver with writeTranscation, then change databse automatically? 
2. If should program with writeTranction,  what kind of format i should initiate, (ol.format.gml or others)?
3. What is featureType, How i know the value of, in order to initiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can always do the transaction directly on the DB but using WFS-T through geoserver will save you time and also will make you compatitable if you deside ,in the future, to change the DB for example from Postgres to Oracle. WFS trnasaction is a protocol accepting the geometry and/or attribute  to insert or modify and then geoserver has to translate the xml to proper SQL insert or update or delete.
2. GML is defenetly supported by geoserver for the transaction. I am not sure whether it support any other format for transactions. You can get an example using GML within the "demo requests" area of your installed geoserver.
3. Featuretype is the layers configured within geoserver. So whenever you add a new layer this is the feature type. The synatx ussually is workspace:layername